# How to automatically ontap in flutter

Tags: flutter, function

Please help i have a video recording app which starts with a tap and a timer is also started with the same tap and after another tap it stops and timer reset . I want to stop and reset timer when the timer reaches 15 second how to do this please help

```
 GestureDetector(
                    onTap: 
                    () async {
                      if (isRecoring) {
                        stop();
                        XFile videopath =
                            await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
                        setState(() {
                          isRecoring = false;

                         
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (builder) => VideoViewPage(
                                        path: videopath.path,
                                      )));
                        }
                        
                        );
                      } else {
                        startTime();
                        await _cameraController.startVideoRecording();

                        setState(() {
                          isRecoring = true;
                          // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                        });
                      }
                    },`
```

i tried adding logical or like this ` if (isRecoring || timer == '15') {stop}  but didnt work.
create a diffrent function with a if condition for stop even that didnt work

Comment: Consider adding some code of what you've tried instead of screenshots

Comment: [Countdown Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) can help you

Comment: you can try stop_watch_timer

Comment: i had figgured out how to use a timer i dont know how to stop the video recording if the timer reach 15 sec

Answer (score 1):

### Firstly you need to define a `Duration` variable and a `Timer` to track the timer duration:

```
var videoDuration = const Duration();
Timer? autoStopRecordingTimer;
```

### Then make a function which will stop the video recording:

```
void stopRecording()async{
      stop();
      XFile videopath = await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
      setState(() {
          isRecoring = false;
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
               builder: (builder) => VideoViewPage(
                     path: videopath.path,
                     )));
                  }
                        
              );
}
```

### When starting video recording, start the timer as well. Which will stop the recording if it has been 15 or more seconds:

```
autoStopRecordingTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
          if(videoDuration.inSeconds>=15){
            autoStopRecordingTimer?.cancel();
            videoDuration = const Duration();
            stopRecording();
          } else {
            videoDuration+=const Duration(seconds: 1);
          }
      });
```

Comment: did the same but get error with context : The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'

Comment: On which line you got this error?

Comment: Stoprecording function

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BxvmhtjrcbTRLJKjNHf21U_m0ECPqFOv/view?usp=drivesdk help me fix that

Comment: Okay, request `BuildContext` and pass it when calling `stopRecording` function. `void stopRecording(BuildContext context) async { ... }`